# Flutter : Exception on using Navigator.of(context) for onPressed event for RaisedButton

Tags: flutter

I am getting this exception

> Exception has occurred.
>   NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: ancestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher'))

on using a custom method (navigateToLogin) that I am passing for the onPressed function, for RaisedButton, however, when I write the same navigation directly on onPressed = (){ ...Navigation code..} it works fine. Is it because it is not getting the context?

```
import 'package:credit/src/pages/credit/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //return HomePage();  // Un coment this method for Homepage
    String loginTxt = "Login";

    // Set login value on click of Login button
    setLoginValue() async {
      SharedPreferences loginCheck = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await loginCheck.setString("userstatus", "loggedin");
      print("Set login value");
      print(loginCheck.getString("userstatus"));
    }

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: SafeArea(
            child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                home: Scaffold(
                    appBar: PreferredSize(
                      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(35),
                      child: AppBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        title: Text("Select Language"),
                        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                        primary: false,
                      ),
                    ),
                    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: navigateToLogin(),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: new Text("Continue",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 20),
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                      ),
                    ),
                    body: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[],
                    )))));
  }

  navigateToLogin() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return HomePage();
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want it work you have to pass `context` as a parameter :

```
navigateToLogin(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return HomePage();
    }));
  }
```

And when you call it :

```
onPressed: () => navigateToLogin(context);
```

Comment: I did try that, but now I am getting an exception  FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.

Comment: I figured it out, i changed the handler to be as a function in the main code, onPressed: () => navigateToLogin(context),  - This fixed the errors, I have edited the code in your answer